# How to execute a piece of code for each element of the result of a dynamic query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a dynamic query in my PostgreSQL function:

```
execute format('select something from %', table_name)
```

I want to run some code for every record returned by the above statement.

**How can I do this?**

My first idea is as follows.

I need to do something like this:

```
execute format('select something from %', table_name)
into my_data;

for my_record in my_data
loop

-- Do something with my_record

end loop;
```

In order to use the above code in a function or procedure, I need to declare the variables `my_data` and `my_record`.

`my_record` has the data type `record`. What could the data type of `my_data` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic statement in a `FOR` loop:

```
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      EXECUTE format('select something from %I', table_name)
   LOOP
      /* "r" now contains a table row */
   END LOOP;
END;
```